# Resize UICollectionView with autolayout causes jump

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

I have a collection view that changes it's contents depending on a selector. It's basically a set of profile tags associated with categories so one can select the first category and view tags associated with that, but tapping another category should refresh the tag list and resize the view with animation. I'm having trouble getting the UICollectionView resize to happen without jumping. I created a sample project that isolates the issue: https://github.com/tamoyal/autolayout-resize-jump

Would love some help if anyone knows why UICollectionView freaks out when being resized with animation. Note - it resizes fine (no jump) without animation.